# Flask: How do I route to page with more info about that query

Tags: python, flask

So I am pretty new at Flask environment and I am making my first app, some kind of Task manager app and I have a question.

I have a template with my tasks listed in table with for loop:

```
{% for task in closed_tasks %}
                        <tr>
                            <td width="300px">{{ task.name }}</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="popover" title="Notes" data-content="{{task.notes}}" data-placement="top" data-animation="true">Notes</button></td>
                            <td width="100px">{{ task.due_date }}</td>
                            <td width="50px">{{ task.priority }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{{ url_for('delete_entry', task_id = task.task_id) }}">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

 {% endfor %}
```

So what I want to do now is when I would click on specific task, I want to be routed on separate page where I can see more infos of that task.

I managed to start with app route where I get the link with related task_id:

```
@app.route("/task_view/<int:task_id>/")
@login_required
def task_view(task_id):
```

But how do I now query and display infos related with that task_id on that page?

Comment: You’ll need to provide a whole lot more information including how you are accessing your DB and your DB schema for such a broad question.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just want to [follow the tutorial example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/views/) and massage it for what you want to do.  Obviously if you have done anything specific to your app, such as a non-standard DB configuration, you should figure out how you are accessing the DB in your app and us that methodology.

```
@app.route("/task_view/<int:task_id>/")
@login_required
def task_view(task_id):
    # get a handle to our db connection
    db = get_db() 
    # query the database for the given task
    # OP did not post schema information, so assumed that the
    # task info was in a table called my_task_table
    cur = db.execute('select * from my_task_table where task_id=?', [ task_id ])
    # retrieve all results from the database
    results = cur.fetchall()
    # grab our task-of-interest
    task = results[0] if results else None
    # render our template using the provided task
    return render_template('task_template.html', task=task)
```

Comment: Yees! Thank you very much :)
So now when I want to present data on that page I just do them with index or any other way?

'code'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
{{task}}
</body>
</html>
'code'

That gives back (14, u'tralalalala', u'lalalala UUUU EEEEE', u'2017-01-27', 10, 1)
So than I can just search out data with indexes...example {{task[0]}}?
I guess that's the idea right?

Comment: That's right, you can just access your fields by index.  You can specify the orde rof the fields to have finer grained control by using the field names instead of `*`.  For example `select task_id, task_name, task_description from my_task_table where task_id=?` so you know that index 0 will be the `task_id` and so on.

Comment: Great, I totally get it now.
Thanks again!